# enumitem: remove period from end of enumeration

Tags: lists, enumerate

I am writing a book with end-of-chapter-problems using the `enumitem` package. I inserted

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\bf\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}}
```

in the preamble to generate the problem numbers, but I would like the exercises in chapter 1 for example to show up as just 1.1, not 1.1. with a period at the end.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it for all items, do it like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\bfseries\thechapter.\arabic*}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla\label{enum:one}
  \item bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}

Here is item~\ref{enum:one}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For only one instance of `enumerate`, this one will do:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Some chapter}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\thechapter.\arabic*]
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla\label{enum:one}
  \item bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}

Here is item~\ref{enum:one}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this did not work! The chapter number is gone, as well as the boldface.

Comment: \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Some chapter}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\bf\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item bla
    \item bla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

Comment: @ShomuBanerjee Use `setlist` as in my code instead of `\renewcommand{\theenumi}`.

Comment: I was showing you my original code. I cut and pasted your code in a new file as a test but could not reproduce what you obtained!

Comment: @ShomuBanerjee Then may be you need to update your tex distribution. Which version of `enumitem` you are using?

Comment: I'm using TeXShop 3.09.

Comment: How do I find out the version of enumitem I'm using?

Comment: @ShomuBanerjee Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and check in the log file under `**Files List**`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `enumitem` package

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Very important chapter}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}}]
    \item blah, blah,
    \item blah.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works but I want this for more than one instance.